# git submodule showing up as a file in git status

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I added a submodule and when I run git status it shows up as a file

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   mysubmodule
```

should I commit this or add it to the .ignore file ?

Comment: After using `git submodule add <subrepo URL>`, you do need to commit the changes. And if your problem has been solved, you can accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever there is a new submodule added, git creates a .gitmodules file and file for the submodule that you have added

.gitmodules file stores the project URL and local subdirectory mapping.

```
[submodule "mysubmodule"]
path = Mysubmodule
url = https://theurl
```

Although Mysubmodule is a subdirectory in your working directory, Git sees it as a submodule and doesn’t track its contents when you’re not in that directory. Instead, Git sees it as a particular commit from that repository.

So, You will need to commit both the .gitmodules file and the submodule file to git.

Please refer to [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for more details.